# Grabbing part of logging message into variable in python

Tags: python, bash, logging

How do I grab a part of a logging message into a variable to then use it on a bash script in python?

Code below

```
if new_file is not None and new_file.get('status', '') != "FAIL":
    message = "Storage service created {}: {}".format(sip_type, new_file)
    logging.info(message)
    print(message)
    sys.exit(0)
```

Generates the following output:

```
Storage service created SIP: {'size': 113509, 'status': 'UPLOADED', 'origin_path': 'currentlyProcessing/teshhdhl88gekkjjgkg29-ccdf0a5b-4eda-4948-99fa-c5947082fa41/teshhdhl88gekkjjgkg29-ccdf0a5b-4eda-4948-99fa-c5947082fa41.7z', 'origin_pipeline': '/api/v2/pipeline/053ec0d5-6510-4b0c-a5ef-2949a2f53e9a/', 'uuid': 'ccdf0a5b-4eda-4948-99fa-c5947082fa41', 'related_package_uuid': None, 'current_path': 'ccdf/0a5b/4eda/4948/99fa/c594/7082/fa41/teshhdhl88gekkjjgkg29-ccdf0a5b-4eda-4948-99fa-c5947082fa41.7z', 'origin_location': '/api/v2/location/8bfed394-bb74-4442-b33c-f0766862daa9/', 'misc_attributes': {}, 'current_full_path': '/var/archivematica/sharedDirectory/www/AIPsStore/ccdf/0a5b/4eda/4948/99fa/c594/7082/fa41/teshhdhl88gekkjjgkg29-ccdf0a5b-4eda-4948-99fa-c5947082fa41.7z', 'current_location': '/api/v2/location/587ecb7a-fb95-4076-a5bc-d80528e0d19f/', 'related_packages': [], 'resource_uri': '/api/v2/file/ccdf0a5b-4eda-4948-99fa-c5947082fa41/', 'package_type': 'AIP'}
```

I need to get 'current_full_path' into a variable to run:

```
dropbox ='/bkpdir'
bashCommand = "bash /home/charles/Dropbox-Uploader/dropbox_uploader.sh upload /VARIABLE WOULD BE HERE " + dropbox
os.system(bashCommand)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to get the `current_full_path` from the `message` variable:

```
import ast

if new_file is not None and new_file.get('status', '') != "FAIL":
    message = "Storage service created {}: {}".format(sip_type, new_file)
    logging.info(message)
    print(message)

    current_full_path = ast.literal_eval(message.split("SIP: ")[1])['current_full_path']

    print current_full_path
    #/var/archivematica/sharedDirectory/www/AIPsStore/ccdf/0a5b/4eda/4948/99fa/c594/7082/fa41/teshhdhl88gekkjjgkg29-ccdf0a5b-4eda-4948-99fa-c5947082fa41.7z

    sys.exit(0)
```

Remember to `return` `current_full_path` if the `if` statement is in a function.

To get `current_full_path` into `bashCommand`, use:

```
dropbox ='/bkpdir'
bashCommand = "bash/home/charles/Dropbox-Uploader/dropbox_uploader.sh upload" + current_full_path + dropbox

print bashCommand
#bash/home/charles/Dropbox-Uploader/dropbox_uploader.sh upload/var/archivematica/sharedDirectory/www/AIPsStore/ccdf/0a5b/4eda/4948/99fa/c594/7082/fa41/teshhdhl88gekkjjgkg29-ccdf0a5b-4eda-4948-99fa-c5947082fa41.7z/bkpdir

os.system(bashCommand)
```

Comment: You can replace `"SIP: "` with `sip_type + ": "` if  the `sip_type` is not always equal to `SIP`

Comment: that works great. Now how do I get the result print current_full_path into bashCommand = "bash /home/charles/Dropbox-Uploader/dropbox_uploader.sh upload "    right after upload?

Comment: I did this localaip = str(current_full_path)
              print(localaip)      and it prints fine, but I cant add it to bashcommand

Comment: Is this what you want in `bashCommand`? `bash/home/charles/Dropbox-Uploader/dropbox_uploader.sh upload/var/archivematica/sharedDirectory/www/AIPsStore/ccdf/0a5b/4eda/4948/99fa/c594/7082/fa41/teshhdhl88gekkjjgkg29-ccdf0a5b-4eda-4948-99fa-c5947082fa41.7z/bkpdir` I have edited the answer to include it. Let me know if this solves the problem.